# How to Avoid "Overfull \hbox" Warning for a Two-Case Equation in Single Column?

Tags: math-mode, two-column, overfull

I have the following equation that spans two cases, and I'm getting an "Overfull \hbox" warning in my two-column document:

```
\documentclass[conference, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

%% Packages:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}                        
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}  
\interdisplaylinepenalty=1000 
\usepackage{mleftright}       
\mleftright                   
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}   

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbf{1}(x \geq 0) \mathbf{1}(-w \leq y - x \leq 0) =
    \begin{cases}
    \mathbf{1}(0 \leq x \leq w + y), & \text{if $-w \leq y \leq 0$},  \\
    \mathbf{1}(y \leq x \leq w + y), & \text{if $ y \geq 0$}.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

What modifications can be made to eliminate the warning without sacrificing the clarity of the equation? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete example that can be compiled. Depending on document class etc. one will see your problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guess what this means, but you would need to split over more lines, perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

%% Packages:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{url}                        
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}  
\interdisplaylinepenalty=1000 
\usepackage{mleftright}       
\mleftright                   
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}   

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{multline*}
    \mathbf{1}(x \geq 0)
    \mathbf{1}(-w \leq y - x \leq 0)
\\{}  =
    \begin{cases}
    \mathbf{1}(0 \leq x \leq w + y), & \text{if $-w \leq y \leq 0$},  \\
    \mathbf{1}(y \leq x \leq w + y), & \text{if $ y \geq 0$}.
    \end{cases}
\end{multline*}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```